# weblogic 10.3.6 classloader shared library

Tags: shared-libraries, persistence, weblogic11g

I have weblogic server 10.3.6. I want to deploy a web app (without maven) with some jars and some shared library. So, I created my shared library and then I deploy my web app, but when server go up I receive this exception

```
<Oct 20, 2016 9:23:11 AM CEST> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Console encountered the following error weblogic.application.ModuleException:
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1520)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:59)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToOne.orphanRemoval()Z
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1641)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:767)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:686)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3512)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3466)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1355)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1756)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:251)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:372)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:357)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:587)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1868)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
```

The problem is that in the weblogic libraries there is an old version of javax.persistence, while the correct version of this library is on my shared-library of hibernate 4.2.3.
So, I check and I understand that the problem is that weblogic load first its libraries and in this way doesn't use my shared library.
Searching on Internet, I see that I can set to load first my shared library using my `weblogic.xml` file, but I get always the same error.
This is my `weblogic.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.3/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.6</wls:weblogic-version>

    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>hibernate</wls:library-name>
        <wls:specification-version>4.2.3</wls:specification-version>
        <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>

    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>spring</wls:library-name>
        <wls:specification-version>3.1.3</wls:specification-version>
        <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>

    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>spring_security</wls:library-name>
        <wls:specification-version>3.1.3</wls:specification-version>
        <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>

    <!-- <wls:library-ref> -->
    <!-- <wls:library-name>zk</wls:library-name> -->
    <!-- <wls:specification-version>6.5.2</wls:specification-version> -->
    <!-- <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match> -->
    <!-- </wls:library-ref> -->

    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>zk_7.0.3</wls:library-name>
        <wls:specification-version>7.0.3</wls:specification-version>
        <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>

    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>dwh_iconset</wls:library-name>
        <wls:specification-version>1.0.0</wls:specification-version>
        <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>

    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>apache_poi_3.9</wls:library-name>
        <wls:specification-version>3.9</wls:specification-version>
        <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>

    <wls:library-ref>
        <wls:library-name>BO</wls:library-name>
        <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
    </wls:library-ref>

    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:context-root>/PORTALE</wls:context-root>

    <wls:session-descriptor>
        <wls:cookie-path>/PORTALE</wls:cookie-path>
    </wls:session-descriptor>


    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>

</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Can you help me? How can I solve this problem?
Thanks